# Updated subclass UITableViewCell with xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My app is mimicking the Apple VoiceMemos app. Where you can select and play audio from within an `UITableViewCell`.

I have a subclassed `UITableViewCell` with an associated xib file. I have a singleton class setup to handle playing the audio. Playing the audio works fine but I can't seem to get the labels in the cell to update correctly. The labels are added and the xib file and should be updating the time left and time remaining.

My audio player singleton class has a block parameter that passes back the timeAlreadyPlayed and timeRemaining as variables like so:

(This is in the AudioTableCell subclass)

```
[PNAudioController sharedController].playBackBlock = ^(NSString* timeAlreadyPlayed, NSString* timeRemaining, NSTimeInterval currentPlaybackTime) {

    NSAssert([NSThread mainThread], @"I need to be on the main thread.");

    NSLog(@"timeAlreadyPlayed = %@", timeAlreadyPlayed);

    //Labels created in xib and liked to UITableViewCell subclass
    self.timeRemainingLabel.text = timeRemaining;
    self.timeAlreadyPlayedLabel.text = timeAlreadyPlayed;
    self.currentTimeSlider.value = currentPlaybackTime;

    [self setNeedsLayout];
};
```

The `NSLog` statement does print out to the console correctly but the labels in the cell do not update correctly. I did see that setting setNeedsLayout should mark it for a redraw in the next update cycle but that doesn't do anything.

Image of what my tableCell looks like, the two "10:00" labels are the ones I'm trying to update:
[image]

Since it is printing out to the console correctly the only thing I can think the problem is that the cell isn't being redrawn properly. I've even tried triggering a reload in the `UIViewController` that contains that `UITableView` datasource and delegate code but that didn't work either.

EDIT: 
In response to rdelmar:

If I log out the label and it's text in the block:

```
VideoContentTypeTest[24158:70b] timeRemainingLabel = <UILabel: 0x10c32a170; frame = (263 39; 42 21); text = '-55.61'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10c329850>>
VideoContentTypeTest[24158:70b] timeRemainingLabel.text = -55.61
```

The label is not nil and it's text **is** being updated properly. It just never gets reflected in the UI.

Comment: If you log self.timeRemainingLabel, what does it give you?

Comment: @rdelmar I've updated my answer. It shows that self.timeRemainingLabel is there in memory. It also shows that it's text has been updated correctly. It just doesn't reflect in the UI

Comment: @random if you were to update the text outside the block, does it work?

Comment: Strange. Override initWithCoder and try setting some text to the label. It should reflect from there at-least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, when you get new data, you would update the array that you use to populate the table view, and then call reloadData. So, I would use your callback block to update an array (probably an array of dictionaries) in the table view controller class, and use that array to populate your cells. I don't think it's a good idea to add data to a table view cell outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: bah! That's what I was afraid of. It was my last option to go back and revise it to use that method. Thanks for your help, I'll accept tomorrow, just want to give it some time to see if anyone else has any magical ideas :-)

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your `self` references for the labels by `[PNAudioController sharedController]` instead and see if that fixes it. Im not an expert on blocks but maybe `self` isn't referring to the custom cell in that scope, not sure.

Comment: The self references are to the UITableViewCell. Those labels were created in a xib and linked to the UITableViewCell subclass. I can't remove self or it creates an error. Thanks for looking at it though

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `setNeedsDisplay`? Afaik you only need `setNeedsLayout` for events such as turning the screen, not for redrawing data.

Also, if you want code executed on the main thread, you can call:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self setNeedsDisplay]; });
```

Comment: setNeedsDisplay doesn't do anything either. The current code is being performed on the main thread, see the NSAssert.

Comment: Depending on your (release) configuration, NSAssert could be disabled.